# Opposite of disableSelection function for enabling text selection for specific HTML elements

Tags: javascript, text, selection

I'm using a JavaScript function called as disableSelection for preventing text selection on specific elements. Declaration of this function is here:

```
function disableSelection(target)
{
    if (typeof target.onselectstart!="undefined") //IE route
        target.onselectstart=function(){return false}
    else if (typeof target.style.MozUserSelect!="undefined") //Firefox route
        target.style.MozUserSelect="none"
    else //All other route (ie: Opera)
        target.onmousedown=function(){return false}
    target.style.cursor = "default"
}
```

I want to disable text selection on the whole page except form elements. If I call disableSelection(document.body), it'll do the job but it'll also disable text selection on form elements (but this happens only on Firefox).

My question is how can I prevent form fields being affected by this text disabler script? I can tag all content except form fields but it requires so much effort.

I'll appreciate any help on this.

Note: I found disableSelection script from [here](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/noselect.htm).

Answer (score 0):

by returning false from an event, you will disable the default behavior of the browser (selecting the text). I would therefor modify the function like this;

```
function disableSelection(target, enable)
{
    if (typeof target.onselectstart!="undefined") //IE route
        target.onselectstart=function(){return enable}
    else if (typeof target.style.MozUserSelect!="undefined") //Firefox route
        target.style.MozUserSelect=enable?"all":"none";
    else //All other route (ie: Opera)
        target.onmousedown=function(){return enable}
    target.style.cursor = "default"
}
```

and then call this for your stuff;

```
disableSelection(document.body, false);
disableSelection(document.forms[0], true);
```

should work (didn't test it)

Comment: It didn't work, but I'll try more. If I succeed, I'll post here.

Comment: To test if it works or not I called disableSelection(document.body, false); and I called disableSelection(document.body, true); right after it. But selection is not enabled on whole page. Any idea?

Comment: I tested it with Firefox 9.0.1. (Note: Original problem does not occur with other browsers even if I use the original script.)

Answer (score 0):

script must be under `<body>` tag. if u want div only disable : `disableSelection(document.getElementById('divName'))`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, only tested in chrome:

```
function enableSelection(target) {
    //For IE This code will work
    if(typeof target.onselectstart != "undefined") {
        target.onselectstart = function() {
            return true;
        }
    }

    //For Firefox This code will work
    else if(typeof target.style.MozUserSelect != "undefined") {
        target.style.MozUserSelect = "all";
    }

    //All other  (ie: Opera) This code will work
    else {
        target.onmousedown = function() {
            return true;
        }
        target.style.cursor = "default";
    }
}
```